# how to speed up the pattern search btw two lists : python

Tags: python, performance, list, large-files, intersect

I have two fastq files like the one given below. Each record in the file starts with '@'. For two such files, my aim is to extract records that are common btw two files.

```
@IRIS:7:1:17:394#0/1
GTCAGGACAAGAAAGACAANTCCAATTNACATTATG
+IRIS:7:1:17:394#0/1
aaabaa`]baaaaa_aab]D^^`b`aYDW]abaa`^
@IRIS:7:1:17:800#0/1
GGAAACACTACTTAGGCTTATAAGATCNGGTTGCGG
+IRIS:7:1:17:800#0/1
ababbaaabaaaaa`]`ba`]`aaaaYD\\_a``XT
```

I have tried this:
first I get a list of read IDs that are common in file1 and 2.

```
import sys
#('reading files and storing all lines in a list')
data1 = open(sys.argv[1]).read().splitlines()
data2 = open(sys.argv[2]).read().splitlines()

#('listing all read IDs from file1')
list1 = []
for item in data1:
  if '@' in item:
    list1.append(item)
#('listing all read IDs from file2')
list2 = []
for item in data2:
  if '@' in item:
    list2.append(item)
#('finding common reads in file1 and file2')
def intersect(a, b):
   return list(set(a) & set(b))

common = intersect(list1, list2)
```

Here, I search for commom IDs in the main file and export the data in a new file. following code works fine for small files but freezes my computer if I try it with larger files. I believe that the 'for' is taking too much memory:

```
#('filtering read data from file1')
mod_data1 = open(sys.argv[1]).read().rstrip('\n').replace('@', ',@')
tab1 = open(sys.argv[1] + '_final', 'wt')
records1 = mod_data1.split(',')
for item in records1[1:]:
  if item.replace('\n', '\t').split('\t')[0] in common:
     tab1.write(item)
```

Please suggest what should I do with the code above, such that it works on larger files(40-100 million records/file, and each record is 4 line).

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, you could write :

```
list1 = [i for item in data1 if '@' in item]
list2 = [i for item in data2 if '@' in item]
```

You could also define them as sets directly using set comprehension (depending on the [version of python you are using)](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features).

```
set1 = {i for item in data1 if '@' in item}
set2 = {i for item in data2 if '@' in item}
```

I'd expect creating the set from the beginning to be faster than creating a list and then make a set out of it.

As for the second part of the code, I am not quite sure yet what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In second part of the code, I am inserting a comma wherever '@' is found and then splitting on this comma. This gives me a list in which each item is a set of 4 lines. Next, I am spliting eact item in Records1[] with a \t, and then searching records1[0] in common[]. If found a match, I am writing that record from records1[] in a new file. Unfortunately, it is taking too long to finish.